# How to target the chrome browser for Mac only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

Hi I have cross browser issue with chrome in mac,I have a css class to fix the issue but thing is how would i target it to chrome that to only in mac?

Many Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript something like below.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Macintosh/) && navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome/))
```

Comment: Thanks for response john but how would i target only chrome from above code/script  We can detect the mac only i need my css only when chrome is opened in Mac

Comment: @Bhairav Updated. You can check.